# Learning C by doing string search

Tags: c

I found this in a code I am currently studying, could someone explain it to me.

```
char * string = "Simulated Annealing = 12847369";
char * value = strchr(string, '=');

*(value ++ ) = 0;


printf("%s ==== %s", value, string);
```

I noticed that string will print in a new line first, why this?

```
char* karmarkar = "Karmarkar   958572";
```

I want to use strchr to find the first occurrence of "space" in string karmarkar.
How do I do that?

Comment: This code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: you can fix it with `char *string = strdup("....");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, `strchr` will return a pointer to the byte where an '=' is found in `string`. You need not append `0` to the returned value as it is just another pointer to the character array pointed to by `string`, which is already null terminated. To print the character, just say `value[0]`:

```
char* string = "Simulated Annealing = 12847369";
char* value = strchr(string, '=');
if (value != NULL)
  {
    printf("value: %s, string: %s\n", value, string);
    printf("char: %c\n", value[0]); /* prints = */
  }
```

Do the same to find a space in the second string:

```
char* karmarkar = "Karmarkar   958572";
value = strchr(karmarkar, ' ');
if (value != NULL)
  printf("value: %s\n", value);
```

Always check the return value of `strchr` before using it, as it returns NULL if the character is not found.

BTW, the statement, `*(value ++) = 0` should cause a segfault as it attempts to modify a read-only location. If you found this code in a book that claims to teach C, I suggest that you move away from it and start learning from [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628). If your compiler generated code that prints a newline for that particular statement, you should start using a better compiler. There are some few good ones [available for free download](http://gcc.gnu.org).

Answer (score 2):

1. Nope, it doesn't put a new line http://codepad.org/xhTiV4Qn . Actually on my machine it gives sigsegv because you are trying to write at a read only location inside "Simulated ... ".
2. `int pos = strchr(karmarkar, ' ') - karmarkar;`. `strchr(karmarkar, ' ')` returns a pointer to the first occurrence of " " (space).

Answer (score 1):

The code first computes the location of the '=' character (as an address, not an index). Then the character at this address is set to 0 and the address of value is set to the next sign. This makes "string" end before the '=' (which is now a 0), as it is 0 terminated and value starts after the '='. So the printf will print out " 12847369 ==== Simulated Annealing " (notices that the spaces are still there).

For you second question it works similar, as Alexandru pointed out in his answer.

Comment: I have additional question then. Where is one not expected to use read-only string?

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**

You define `string` to point to a constant string literal, which is stored in read-only memory:

```
char * string = "Simulated Annealing = 12847369";
```

Then you find the first occurrence of `=` in this string and put the pointer to it in `value`:

```
char * value = strchr(string, '=');
```

So `value` now points to a read-only memory or `value = NULL`, so this is a line that has undefined behavior:

```
*(value ++ ) = 0; // assign value to read-only memory
```

if let's say you wrote

```
char string[] = "Simulated Annealing = 12847369";
```

You were storing this string in an array on the stack, and then you could've written to it.

**Now, to your question**

Your code will not print it to a new line, if you wrote anything before that, you'd see that:

```
char string[] = "Simulated Annealing = 12847369";
char * value = strchr(string, '=');
*(value ++ ) = 0;
printf("First line");
printf("%s ==== %s", value, string);
```

To find the first occurrence of the **space** character, use `strchar(karmarkar, ' '):`.

And once again, when you use `strchr` check if the return value is `NULL`, since it might be, and if it is NULL indeed then your program will probably crash. (dereferencing illegal address)